Passing a function to `across()` inside `mutate()`
Here is what I want to achieve
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% dplyr::summarise(
  dplyr::across(mpg, ~ sum(.x) / sum(vs))
) 
#> mpg
#> 1 45.92143

if I have this function stored in an object, I get an error.
f <- ~ sum(.x) / sum(vs) 
mtcars %>% dplyr::summarise(
  dplyr::across(mpg, ~ sum(.x) / sum(vs))
)
#> Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `dplyr::across(mpg, rlang::eval_tidy(f))`.
#> Caused by error in `across()`:
#> ! Can't compute column `mpg`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! objet 'vs' introuvable

What is the magic rlang operator to achieve what I want?
Potential explanation in https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6707

You need to define f as a function using function. Then, you can use that function inside the summarise.
f <- function(x, y) {sum(x) / sum(y)}

mtcars |> 
  dplyr::summarise(
    dplyr::across(mpg, ~ f(.x, vs))
  )

#      mpg
#1 45.92143

